# Why pgAdmin4 invoke "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 42: invalid continuation byte" error?

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, pgadmin-4

I'm newbie in postgreSQL ,when I'm trying to create a new local server using pgAdmin4 ,it shows me this error :

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 42: invalid continuation byte
```

I'm using windows 7 as my OS.

**My steps to create a new server :**

[image: Step1][image]

Answer (score 0):

Was your language set to en_US when you installed it? Some people claim it has issues with language settings for similar errors. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897521/postgresql-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe9-in-position-42-invalid-continua